# how to set cron job with specific time interval ?

Tags: cron

I need to run a cron job with 50 min time interval running with following schedule:

`14:00, 
14:50,
15:40,
16:30,
17:20,
18:10`

Any help or direction appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cron doesn't understand intervals. You will have to have a separate cron job for each of those.

```
00 14 * * * ...
50 14 * * * ...
40 15 * * * ...
30 16 * * * ...
20 17 * * * ...
10 18 * * * ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Does the specific 50-minute interval matter? Would something like the following work? The first entry in the cron listing below denotes the interval range. So "every 50 minutes". If you need the *specific* times rather than "once every 50 minutes", then you're better off hardcoding the intervals. Also see: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/crontab-every-10-min/

```
*/50 *    *    *    *       exec /usr/local/bin/script.sh
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```